# Design some design with bootstrap 4 with flex-containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to design layout like:
[image]

Description:

- A and B component should have a 50% width and 100% height od all page.
- C component should be horizontally and vertically centered.
- D component should be at the top.
- A contains C.
- B contains D.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.row-height100
{
  min-height: 100%;
}

</style>

</head>
<body class="d-flex">

<div class="flex-fill flex-row row-height100 justify-content-center">
<div class="flex-fill p-2 bg-success d-flex justify-content-center row-height100">
        <div>Flex item 1</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-fill p-2 bg-success d-flex justify-content-start row-height100">Flex item 2</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change your body or a div element wrapping the elements to a *flexbox* using **`d-flex`** and use **`h-100`** to make the flexbox full-height.
2. And **`flex-fill`** to both your **`"A"`** and **`"B"`** elements to make them share and occupy 50% of the full width.
3. Change both your **`"A"`** and **`"B"`** elements to a flexbox too using **`d-flex`**.
4. Horizontally center both your **`"C"`** and **`"D"`** elements' content using **`justify-content-center`**.
5. Vertically center-align your **`"C"`** element's content using **`align-items-center`**.
6. Vertically top-align your **`"D"`** element's content using **`align-items-start`**.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I have described above:

```css
/* CSS */

html, body {height: 100%;width: 100%;}
body {min-height: 100%;background-color: blue;}

/* ignore following two css properties. Added just for visual example's sake */
.flex-fill {border: 4px solid #000;}
.flex-fill div {border: 4px solid #000; background-color: #FFF; padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<!-- Scripts -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- HTML -->

<div class="d-flex h-100">
    <div class="flex-fill d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-success">
      <div>Flex item 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill d-flex justify-content-center align-items-start bg-success">
      <div>Flex item 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
html {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
}

.a, .b {
  flex:1;
  position: relative;
}

.a {
  border-right:2px solid;
}

.c {
  border:2px solid;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  top:50%;
}

.d {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  top:20px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 70px;
  border:2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
<div class="b">
  <div class="d"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add explain to your answer

Comment: Thanks for fast answer but I really want to use Bootstrap in my project.

Comment: Other user will come in future and want to understand what your answer is... and I am woman :)

Comment: @לבנימלכה ok :)

Comment: @KeyB0rys sorry, I can't use bootstrap.